# Real-time notification feature in MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am trying to build a web app where users can receive notifications if their posts get likes. This functionality is actually working but the notification component renders only when the page reloads. But I want it to re-render the notification component as soon as there is a change that occurs with it. I am trying to make this work with SocketIO both in client and server but it feels like there should be a way easier way to solve this issue. How?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use [server-sent events (SSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), which can be seen as a uni-directional
and simplified version of WebSocket (only server can send data to clients). You might need route param or query string so that users can connect to different channels.

---

If it doesn't have to be so real-time (i.e. receiving notifications 1 minute after somebody liked the post is okay), you could also try (long)polling.

However, since `post-like` table may contain a huge amount of data, constantly querying it is expected to result in bad performance on the server. Also, adding an extra column to mark if the user has been notified about a specific like is trivial.

A possible workaround might be to create a new table, say `pending-like-notification`, which is used to stored all pending like notifications. Whenever a post is liked, we insert a new record into this table.

Therefore, when a user tries to query if any of his posts is liked recently, in the backend we lookup this table instead of the `post-like` table, and delete the selected rows after the user has been notified so that the amount of data in this table can stay low (hopefully).

All in all, in this scenario, I think SSE and WebSocket will be better choices.